# Maven Assembly Plugin is executed on child projects

Tags: maven-assembly-plugin

I have the following problem. I have a multimodule project. I want to run maven-assembly plugin on the toplevel pom that is also a parent pom for its modules. I want the plugin to be executed only on the top level pom. Currently it tries to execute also on all the submodules. I do not want this as I just need to grab all the sources from all the modules and submodules in one place (toplevel target directory.)

Here is my descriptor:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>src</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <includeSubModules>true</includeSubModules>
        <sources>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
            <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
                    <includes>
                        <include>src/main/**</include>
                        <include>src/test/**</include>
                        <include>target/classes/**</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

The pom file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
      >

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>myid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartid</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</parent>
<groupId>myid2</groupId>
<artifactId>TopLevelBuild</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>5.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Some Application</name>
<modules>
    <module>1</module>
    <module>2</module>
    <module>3</module>
    <module>4</module>
    <module>5</module>
    <module>6</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Parent pom just contains some dependencies that I want to be inheritaed in all modules. Submodules have the current pom as parent. 
Now if I run :

> mvn assembly:single -Ddescriptor=somedes.xml

it runs ok on the toplevel pom and collect all the sources that I need. But it does not stop and start to execute this goal on all the subprojects, and of course there is no descriptor defined for the. How can I force the execution only on the toplevel pom?

```
...
[INFO] Processing sources for module project: LAST MODULE
[INFO] Building zip: ..../target/TopLevelBuild-5.5-SNAPSHOT-src.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building deploy
[INFO]    task-segment: [assembly:single]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Processing sources for module project: module1-submodule1:jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Processing sources for module project: module1-submodule1:jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Building zip: .../module1/target/module1-5.5-SNAPSHOT-src.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building module1
[INFO]    task-segment: [assembly:single]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [assembly:single {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive src: You must set at least one file.
```

I have tried to add:

> -Dexecution.inherited=false

but it doesn't help.Adding

> -Dassembly.ignoreMissingDescriptor=true

also didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Dassembly.runOnlyAtExecutionRoot=true

This is the property that makes it work as described.

Answer (score 8):

Put this into the configuration of the maven-assembly-plugin, in the parent pom.

```
<runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>true</runOnlyAtExecutionRoot>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you tried to use the `param "-Dexecution.inherited=false"`.

I defined the non-inheritance by xml tag `<inherited>false</inherited>` in the pom.xml of the children module, it seems to work.

Comment: Can you write the tag you are talking about, and where do you specify it. Anyway there should be another solution as when you have 300 projects it takes some time, besides that I do not want to block inheritance for the rest of the things.

Comment: Actually, IMO <inherited>false</inherited> needs to be in the **parent** pom.xml - that way, submodules do not inherit that execution. Not sure if applicable in your situation. See my answer.

Comment: Will not work :( That is exactly what -Dexecution.inherited=false does.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the situation. But to disable execution of a plugin, try this:

```
        <!-- Don't run the reporting tool in submodule. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions combine.self="override" combine.>
                <execution><id>reporting</id><phase>none</phase></execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You need to know the execution id from parent and put it to this snippet into ....

Here's a nice clear explanation: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the `maven-assembly-plugin` within maven phase **none**.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>none</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```